# Condition based rendering in asp.net MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, webforms, partial

I have a page which has 'n' number of panels and each panel need to be rendered based on certain condition and then the panel content as well rendered based on condition.

The page design can be shown below.

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/08/08/PanelArrangment.png

I have to add too much of if statement which makes my code ugly.

```
<div class="panel-body clearfix">

 <% if (/* some condtion */)
   { %>
<divclass="PanelGroup clearfix">
    <label>
       Name
    </label>
    <div class="field_area">
        <%=Html.ComplexComponent()%>
    </div>
</div>

<% }%>
<label>
   Duration
</label>
<% if (/* some condtion */)

<div class="PanelGroup clearfix">
    <label>
       Time
    </label>
    <div class="field_area">
        <%=Html.TextBox("Time", "", new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength =10, @class = "small" })%>
    </div>
</adiv>

<% if (/* some condtion */)

<div class="PanelGroup clearfix">
    <label>
       DurationId
    </label>
    <div class="field_area">
         <%=Html.TextBox("DurationId", "", new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength =10, @class = "small" })%>
    </div>
</div>

<% }%>
```

After some changes I managed to reduce the condition by moving some of them to html helpers and below is my current code.

```
<%      
using (Html.Panel())
    {
        using (var row = Html.PanelRow("Name"))
        {
          if(row.canShow) {
            <%=Html.ComplexComponent()%>
          }
        }

%>
  <label>
  Panel
  </label>

   <% 
     using (var row = Html.PanelRow("Time"))
    {
     if(row.canShow) {
    %>
     <%=Html.TextBox("Time", "", new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength =10, @class = "small" })%>
<%          
     }}
     using (var row = Html.PanelRow("Duration"))
     {
      if(row.canShow) {
     %>
     <%=Html.TextBox("Duration", "", new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength =10, @class = "small" })%>
     <%
      }}
      }
     %>
```

I am just wondering is there any better way than this to make my code better?

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3.0 with web forms and not possible to use Razor view.

Comment: It look Ok. If you feel multiple if conditions are making your code readablity harder, move it to htmlhelperfactory and send the type and return the appropriate MvcString type or control. As long as code looks simple and understandable by any one who may work in future, it is good.